# NSOpenPanel New Document button not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, icloud, nsopenpanel

I can't seem to get the Open Panel's New Document button to work.  Currently I am just using the default application provided Open Panel (iCloud enabled OS X app) which has a New Document button at bottom left of the window.

However I just get a system beep when I click on it, I would expect this button would do the same as File->New menu option but it does nothing other than beep.

How can I either enable this button to simply create a new blank file or remove it altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured it out.

It seems the New Document button is somehow hardware to the CMD+N keystrokes.  I had reassigned CMD+N to apply Normal style to text and this breaks the New Document button.

Seems odd that the button is not wired to newDocument method on First Responder rather than to a keystroke combination.

EDIT
I logged a Bug ID# 14886108 and it seems it may be fixed in Mavericks